# No association found for name `user'. Has it been defined yet? Nested Attributes Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

Building a rails 5 app, using devise and acts_as tennant.

Not too sure where I'm going wrong, I'm trying to create the account and the owner of the account in the same form under accounts/new.

at present I'm getting the following error:

**ArgumentError at /accounts/new
No association found for name `user'. Has it been defined yet?**

[image]

I've gone through my models and controllers and cant seem to figure this out.

**Account.rb**

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  RESTRICTED_NAMES = ["www", "admin", "loadflo"]

  has_many :users

  before_validation :downcase_name, :create_account_name
  strip_attributes only: :account_name, regex: /[^[:alnum:]_-]/

  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true,
                   uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false},
                   exclusion: { in: RESTRICTED_NAMES, message: "This is a restricted name. Please try again or contact support." }

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

private

  def downcase_name
    self.name = name.try(:downcase)
  end

  def create_account_name
    self.account_name = self.name
  end

end
```

**accounts_controller.rb**

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_account, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @accounts = Account.all
  end

  def show

  end

  def new
    @account = Account.new
    @account.build_user
  end

  def edit

  end

  def create
    @account = Account.new(account_params)

    if @account.valid?
      @account.save
      flash[:success] = "Account created successfully."
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  def update

  end

  def destroy

  end

private

  def account_params
    params.require(:account).permit(:name, user_attributes: [:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name, :mobile_tel])
  end

  def set_account
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_tenant(:account)
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable, :trackable

end
```

I also have account_id:integer set on my user table so it can make the association on create like so:

```
add_column :users, :account_id, :integer
add_index  :users, :account_id
```

Thanks in advance for your help here. I think it's something small I'm overlooking.

Comment: Try with plural :users

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have

```
has_many :users
```

So you have to use

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
```

Comment: One thing I notice is that even if you have the correct reference names, you have to define the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` AFTER the `has_many` definition

Comment: @RafaelFontoura Thanks for your comment! That was actually the issue I had and I wasted so much time not thinking about this!